Trino cluster returns query not found error when using trino:jdbc
I have a Trino cluster running in kubernetes. I'm issuing queries to it from another kubernetes pod using Trino JDBC. I get the following error:
java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query: Error fetching next at
http://trino.svc.cluster.local:8080/v1/statement/queued/20240513_205611_00001_ws7bu/y0db0f2ba2338cf8a5b131509ba97808a6857ae88/1 
returned an invalid response: 
JsonResponse{statusCode=404, headers={content-length=[15], content-type=[text/plain], date=[Mon, 13 May 2024 20:56:11 GMT], server=[envoy], x-envoy-upstream-service-time=[3]}, hasValue=false} 
[Error: Query not found]"

The queries were working fine last week. I've tried running the same queries using Trino CLI and they work fine.
What is causing these errors and how do I fix them?

This was happening because there was more than one instance of the coordinator running in our kubernetes cluster. So the workers didn't know which one to use.
After we went back to a single coordinator, this error went away
